# VueJS - variable is defined but never used (Sending Data to Firebase)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an issue when learning VueJS. I want to send data to Firebase, but it keeps telling me that the variables never used. I declare it inside a promise.

This is the script:

```
methods: {
        register: function() {
          const info = {
            email: this.email,
            password: this.passOne,
            displayName: this.displayName
          };

          if(!this.error) {
              Firebase.auth()
              .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(info.email, info.password)
              .then( 
                userCredentials => {
                  this.$router.replace('meetings');
                },
                error => {
                  this.error = error.message;
                }
              );
          }
        }
    },
```

This is the error:

```
error    'userCredentials' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats an es-lint error. To solve:

```
            if(!this.error) {
              Firebase.auth()
               .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(info.email, info.password)
              .then( 
                 () => {
                    this.$router.replace('meetings');
               },
```

or you can also ask es-lint to do not look for the next line:

```
           //es-lint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
           .then( userCredentials => {
              this.$router.replace('meetings');
            },
```

Comment: I tried to change `userCredentials` to `userData'. it's an error not a warning: take a look here: https://prnt.sc/tagpto

Comment: Still my solution works. Yes is an error, the error that you create a variable out of the result of your async function but then you do not use it, so es-lint is giving you that error. I said warning, because without es-lint the code will still run, it will just hold a useless variable

Comment: you only take off an error. the data doesn't go to database. I tried that before I posted here

Comment: I'm sorry, but what you are saying is not true. If you remove you usercredentials argument, and change it to (), your code will not generate that error. If is not saving the result in the database, thats another question, and the error is elsewhere

Comment: Again, apply the first solution I propose, and you can see yourself

Answer (score 0):

replace your `$router.replace(...)` code like below

```
this.$router.replace({ name: 'meetings', params: { credentials: userCredentials } })
```

hope it will solve your issue.